# How to create a ribbon plot?

Tags: r

I'm wanting to create a ribbon plot (really it's a line plot of multiple groups of a categorical variable) but displayed in a 3d style.  This would look something like this:

[image: Ribbon plot example]

So maybe we would want to plot the following sample data as a ribbon plot:

```
set.seed(10)
fun <- function(i) data.frame(person=rep(LETTERS[i], 26), 
    letter=letters, count=sample(0:100, 26, T))
dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:10, function(i) fun(i)))

library(ggplot2) #a traditional 2-d line plot of the data
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=letter, y=count, group=person, color=person)) + 
    geom_line()
```

How can this be achieved in R?  I know there may be better ways to display the data but my interest currently is in producing the ribbon style plot.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hopefully the example below will help point you in the right direction:

```
# data
mat <- matrix(dpois(rep(1:20, 10), lambda=rep(10:1, each=20)), ncol=10)

# 2d line plot
matplot(mat, type="l", col="black", lty=1)

# 3d ribbon plots
par(mar = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
persp(z=mat[,rep(seq(ncol(mat)), each=2)], r=5, theta=320, phi=35, shade=0.5,
      border=NULL, col=rep(c("#808080FE","#00000000"), each=nrow(mat)-1))
persp(z=mat[,rep(seq(ncol(mat)), each=2)], r=5, theta=320, phi=35, shade=0.5,
      border=NA, col=rep(c("#808080FE","#00000000"), each=nrow(mat)-1))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
par(mar = c(5,4,4,2)+.1)
```

[image: ribbon_example]

As you can see, the basic idea here is pretty simple. We organize our values to be plotted into a matrix, duplicate the columns in the matrix so that they are in pairs, and then plot the values using `persp()`, making sure to alternate between transparent and opaque colors. However, there are a few tricky details that remain to be worked out, particularly regarding what to do with the border parameter. I will leave those details to you.

Hope this helps.